# How to make the selectedValue allow case-insensitive set

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I want to be able to set the value of a knockout `observable` that is the `value` of a `select` with *`case-insensitivity`*.  So in my below example passing `justin` would set the `selectedValue` to `Justin`.

### **Not Working: *[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/j9Zh5/)***

### **Working: *[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/j9Zh5/1/)***

**HTML**

```
<select id="people" data-bind="options: peopleList, value: selectedPerson, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'">
</select>
```

**JS**

```
function MyViewModel(defaultPerson) {
    var self = this;
    self.selectedPerson = ko.observable(defaultPerson);
    self.peopleList = ko.observableArray(["Justin", "Sam", "Chris", "John"]);
}

$(function(){
    var person = 'justin';
    var viewModel = new MyViewModel(person);

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can can render options by yourself and don't use `options` binding. This will allow you to convert value to lowercase:

```
<select id="people" data-bind="value: selectedPerson, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'">
    <option value=''>Choose...</option>
    <!-- ko foreach: peopleList -->
        <option data-bind='value: $data.toLowerCase(), text: $data'></option>
    <!-- /ko -->
</select>
```

Here is working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9Zh5/2/)

Comment: This definitely would work, I was hoping for a more built-in solution.  I almost said elegant but I don't think i'm going to find that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `optionsValue` and `optionsText` bindings to render entries "as is" while keeping value case-insensitive.

```
function MyViewModel(defaultPerson) {
    var self = this;
    var Person = function(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.ciName = name.toLowerCase();
    };
    self.selectedPerson = ko.observable(defaultPerson);
    self.ciSelectedPerson = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.selectedPerson().toLowerCase();
    });
    self.peopleList = ko.observableArray(
        ["Justin", "Sam", "Chris", "John"].map(
            function(s) { return new Person(s) }));
}
```

Markup:

```
<select id="people" data-bind="options: peopleList, optionsValue: 'ciName', optionsText: 'name', value: ciSelectedPerson, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'">
</select>
```

Comment: A very good answer +1, I return my results from the mapping plugin but could definitely add this functionality.